# Python requests read timeout error on POST

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am posting form data to a configuration page on a remote machine. The following code works in that the remote configuration occurs but for some reason, I am getting a read timeout error.

```
def postData(url, user, password, data, timeout=10):
    from requests import Session
    from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
    session = Session()
    response = session.post(
        url=url,
        auth=HTTPDigestAuth(user, password),
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            },
        data=data,
        timeout=timeout
    )
    return response
```

The error I get is:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.132.220', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
r = postData(url, usr, pwd, data)
```

I understand that I can wrap it in a try catch block to handle the error but I don't understand why I'm getting a ReadTimeout error in the first place. Ideas?

Comment: That ip address looks like a local IP address, can you see if you can actually `ping` it

Comment: Yes, I can. The POST actually works. If I set the timeout to 100 I don't get the error...

Comment: Then why not set the timeout, maybe the network is slow! try a manual curl post and time it

Comment: If increasing the timeout didn't fix the problem for someone,  try configuring the size of the socket buffer (SO_RCVBUF )